# Advantages between slice notation and for loop iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

What are the relative advantages of using slice notation as opposed to using a for loop?

For example, the following code snippets are equivalent:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
a[1:2][:]
for i in range(1,2):
    for j in range(3):
         a[i][j]
```

Comment: Readability.  This question  is a bit out-of-scope for stack overflow, though.

Comment: `numpy` can do the slice at a lower and more optimised level. Using the nested `for` loop has to have the interpreter do extra work.

Comment: The first version is much clearer that you want the whole of the second row (`a[1][:]` would be better still) and is likely much faster than iterating over the array.

Comment: neither is numpythonic.  `a[1:2, :]` is better

Comment: @jonrsharpe `a[1:2]` and `a[1]` have different number of dimensions

Comment: @wim that's true, although the second "snippet" just gives the values one at a time, so it's not entirely clear what's needed. And +1 for *"numpythonic"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readability and time performance.

Slice notation in python is more efficient because it is implemented at lower level. An example, if you want to copy a list `a` ,always would be more efficient do `a[:]` than list(a) or just iterate over a list.

```
b = a[:]           0.039ms
b = list(a)        0.085ms
```